# Shopify Android Buy SDK gradle build error

Tags: android

I received this error when I imported the android buy SDK into the Android Studio

> Using multiple versions of the Android Gradle plugin in the same build
>   is not allowed.

```
'E:\Android_Projects\MobileBuy\buy3' is using version 3.1.0
'E:\Android_Projects\MobileBuy\buy3-pay-support' is using version 3.1.0
'E:\Android_Projects\MobileBuy\sample' is using version 3.1.4"
```

help please!

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile Buy Sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android) version 3.2.4 has been released, so why do you use 3.1.0 or 3.1.4?

Use version 3.2.4:

```
implementation 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3:3.2.4'
```

Pay Attention: use the same version for all!